# Ошибка при сборке Makefile

Tags: linux, ubuntu, makefile

При попытке сборки проекта, выкидывается ошибка : [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строки 64-66:

```
flash:
    @$(AVRDUDE) -C$(AVRDUDE_CONF) -F -v -p$(MCU) -carduino -P$(UPLOAD_PORT)
-b$(UPLOAD_PORT_BAUD) -D -Uflash:w:build/$(PROJECT_NAME).hex:i
```

Весь код Makefile:

```
# Назва проекту
PROJECT_NAME = test_blink
# Модель мікроконтролера
MCU = atmega328p
# Частота тактового генератора
F_CPU = 16000000UL
# Порт для програмування
UPLOAD_PORT=/dev/ttyUSB0
# Шридкість передачі даних [19200 -(nano atmega168p), 57600 -(nano atmega328p), 115200 -(uno)]
UPLOAD_PORT_BAUD=57600
# Sources files needed for building the application
#SRC = $(wildcard *.c)
SRC = main.c
SRC +=
# The headers files needed for building the application
INCLUDE = -I.
INCLUDE +=
#--------------------------------------------------------------
PROJECT_NAME := $(strip $(PROJECT_NAME))
THIS_DIR := $(dir $(abspath $(firstword $(MAKEFILE_LIST))))
#OBJS:=$(SRC: .c=.o)
OBJS:= $(addsuffix .o,$(basename $(SRC)))
OBJS:= $(addprefix build/,$(OBJS))
CC = avr-gcc
OBJCOPY = avr-objcopy
AVRDUDE = avrdude
AVRDUDE_CONF = /etc/avrdude.conf
TARGET_DIR = build
RM = rm -rf

CFLAGS =-Os
CFLAGS +=-Wall
CFLAGS +=-fpack-struct
CFLAGS +=-fshort-enums
CFLAGS +=-ffunction-sections
CFLAGS +=-fdata-sections
CFLAGS +=-std=gnu99
CFLAGS +=-funsigned-char
CFLAGS +=-funsigned-bitfields

.PHONY: all

all: $(TARGET_DIR) clean build/$(PROJECT_NAME).hex sizedummy
build/$(PROJECT_NAME).hex: build/$(PROJECT_NAME).elf
    @echo Create exec file $@
    @$(OBJCOPY) -O ihex -R .eeprom $< $@
    @echo BUILD SUCCESS!
build/$(PROJECT_NAME).elf: $(OBJS)
    @echo Building target: $@
    @$(CC) -Os -mmcu=$(MCU) -o $@ $^
build/%.o: %.c
    @echo Compile file: $<
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -mmcu=$(MCU) -DF_CPU=$(F_CPU) -o $@ -c $<

$(TARGET_DIR):
    mkdir $(TARGET_DIR)

.PHONY: clean sizedummy

sizedummy:
    @echo
    @avr-size --format=avr --mcu=$(MCU) build/$(PROJECT_NAME).elf

flash:
    @$(AVRDUDE) -C$(AVRDUDE_CONF) -F -v -p$(MCU) -carduino -P$(UPLOAD_PORT)
-b$(UPLOAD_PORT_BAUD) -D -Uflash:w:build/$(PROJECT_NAME).hex:i

clean:
    @$(RM) build/*.o build/$(PROJECT_NAME).elf build/$(PROJECT_NAME).hex
```

Comment: Строки 65-66 должны быть одной строкой

Comment: Спасибо огромное, что-то затупил..